# Loop in clojure with or condition

Tags: function, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to write a function in clojure that calls a condition for each value in a vector; the function should return the OR of the result of the condition applied to each value. Eg I have a vector [1 2 3 4] and a condition (>= x 3) where x is an element in the vector, then the function should return true (similary [0 1 0 1] should return false).

I wrote the method

```
(defn contains-value-greater-or-equal-to-three [values]
    (or (for [x values] (>= x 3)))
)
```

but for the vector [1 2 3 4] this just yields (false false true true); what I want instead is the 'or' function applied to these values.

I'm quite new to functional programming and clojure, let me know if I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the function `some`, that takes a predicate and a collection as arguments, and returns true iff the predicate returns true for some item in the collection.

```
(some #(>= % 3) [1 2 3 4]) ; => true
(some #(>= % 3) [0 1 0 1]) ; => false
```

The problem with your method is that `for` returns a sequence of true/false values, while `or` expects a number of individual arguments. Given only one argument, `or` will return that.  What you could have done is to `reduce` the sequence returned by `for`, like this:

```
(reduce #(or %1 %2) (for [x values] (>= x 3)))
```

(since `or` is a macro, not a function, `(reduce or ...)` will not work.